# Scroll events stop working in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I am developing a website that has scrolling transitions on the "index" page and then normal scrolling with a sticky navigation bar on other pages. The site also uses ajax to transition from one page to the next. I have an if statement based on if the user is on the index page use the scrolling transitions, else use normal scrolling with the sticky navigation.

The problem I've found is that in safari when I click on a link from the index page, scroll on the new page and then go back to the index page, the scroll transitions are not activated again. In fact it seems that the scroll events I have set up stop working entirely.

However this problem does not occur in any other browser: Chrome, IE, Edge or Firefox.

I don't know if it's best for me to post the code for it on here because it is a bit long. But here is a link to the code: http://www.dreshaddev.dreamhosters.com/layout/js/scripts.js

Here is a link to the development site: http://www.dreshaddev.dreamhosters.com/layout/index.php

I have tried multiple solutions like reinstating the same code after an ajax call and removing event listeners and re-adding them back in. I'm not sure what to do. I am testing this on Safari 9.1.3.